# Iterative sum in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sum

I am trouble in develop this algorithm in Java, follow it:

I have an array of doubles and one variable double.

I need develop an algorithm that sum values of an array with a variable - that´s part is ok.

The problem is: I need iterate this sum over x-times (for example 2 times, 3 times, ... or 80 times) and, the value of the variable sum with all value of the array and, it "spreads" its value to values in array, for example:

```
1.0 - double variable
0.1 - 1st value in array
0.5 - 2nd value in array
0.8 - 3rd value in array
```

in the first iteration, we have - don´t horry about the 0.333! ;)

```
formule = 0.1 + (1 * 0.3333) = 0.433
formule = 0.5 + (1 * 0.333) = 0.8333
formule = 0.8 + (1 * 0.333) = 1.1333
```

so, we have to sum all results with the double variable, then

```
0.433 + 0.833 + 1.1333 + 1 = 2.4
```

the, in the next iteration, the 2.4 value and all other values will be replaced in the formula

```
formule = 0.433 + (2.4 * 0.3333) = 1.2325
formule = 0.833 + (2.4 * 0.333) = 1.63325
formule = 1.133 + (2.4 * 0.333) = 1.932
```

so, we have to sum all results with the new double variable (2.4), then

```
1.2325 + 1.63325 + 1.932 + 2.4 = 4.799
```

and, the process repeat until the iteration finish!

This algorithm is based on the Similarity Flooding, proposed by Melnik.

Follow my algorithm

```
 double [] sfAttributes = new double [3]; 

    double [] sfNewAttributes = new double [3]; 

    double [] simLinksAttributes = {0.1, 0.5, 0.8}; // array with values

    double sfClass = 0.0d;

    double simLinkClass = 1.0d; // the double variable!

    int iter = 3; // amout of iterations

    // set the first iteration value
    for (int i = 0; i < similaridadeLinksAtributos.length; i++){


        sfAttributes[i] = simLinkAttributes[i] + (simLinkClass * 0.333);

        // here, sum all values of the simLinkAttributes[i]
        // and put the results in sfClass variable
        sfClass +=  similaridadeLinksAtributos[i];

    }

    sfClasses = (sfClasses + simLinkClass);

 // here starts the iterations.

    for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < simLinkAttributes.length; j++){


            sfNewAttributes[j] = sfAttributes[j] + (sfClass * 0.333);

            sfClass +=  sfNewAttributes[j];


    }

}
```

The results that I need achieve is in following:

```
/* Results
         * 
         *       0 Interaction
         * 2,4 - simLinkClass variable
         * 0,433 - 1st new value of array
         * 0,833 - 2nd new value of array
         * 1,133 - 3rd new value of array
         * 
         *      1st Interaction
         * 4,799 - simLinkClass variable
         * 1,2325 - 1st new value of array
         * 1,63325 - 2nd new value of array
         * 1,932 - 3rd new value of array
         * 
         *      2nd Iteraction
         * 9,58675 - simLinkClass variable
         * 2,830567 - 1st new value of array
         * 2,3227562 -  2nd new value of array
         * 3,530067 -  3rd new value of array
         * 
         *      
         * 
         */
```

Comment: What problems are you facing now and how do your actual results differ from your desired results?

Comment: 1.2325 + 1.63325 + 1.932 + 2.4 = 4.799 ????

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    double[] sfAttributes = new double[3];
    double[] simLinksAttributes = {0.1, 0.5, 0.8}; // array with values
    double sfClass = 0.0d;
    double simLinkClass = 1.0d; // the double variable!
    int iter = 3; // amout of iterations

    // set the first iteration value
    for (int i = 0; i < simLinksAttributes.length; i++) {
        sfAttributes[i] = simLinksAttributes[i] + (simLinkClass * 0.333);
        // here, sum all values of the simLinkAttributes[i]
        // and put the results in sfClass variable
        sfClass += simLinksAttributes[i];
    }
    double[] sfNewAttributes = sfAttributes;

    sfClass = (sfClass + simLinkClass);
    System.out.println(sfClass);
    // here starts the iterations.

    for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < simLinksAttributes.length; j++) {
            sfNewAttributes[j] = sfNewAttributes[j] + (sfClass * 0.333);
        }

        for (int k =0 ; k < sfNewAttributes.length; k++) {
            sfClass += sfNewAttributes[k];
        }
        System.out.println(sfClass);
    }
```